# How can I add an UIImageView to the right side of a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I try to show an `UIImageView` at the very right side of a navigation bar.

I tried to add an **UIViewcontrol** to the navigation bar, sized it as big as I could and then add an `UIImageView` to it with a trailing space of 0.

In the storyboard it looks alright but when I run the app on my iPhone there's a huge space between the image and the right side.

Is there any way to remove this space?

edit:
As you can see there is a huge space at the right side on the iPhone which isn't in the storyboard. Since I tried to do it just with the storyboard there's no code that I could show.

[image: Image iPhone]

[image: Image storyboard]

Comment: do u have any screen shot or sample code?

Comment: I added some screenshots :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIImageBarButton with the method **initWithImage:style:target:action:** or with **initWithCustomView:** and add it to the navigation item as the right bar button item:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]; 
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) But when I use an `UIBarButtonItem` it colors the image blue. Is there a way to let the image at it's original color? And can I round the corners of an `UIBarButtonItem` like the image in my screenshots?

Comment: I see. Than you should use initWithCustomView method. Create UIImageView, assign image, round corners, create UIImageBarButton from that image view and assign to rightBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom view and assign it to navigationItem.titleView

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *temp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...]; 
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    [temp addSubview:image];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = temp;
}
```

Comment: by assigning view to navigationItem.title you can have both title label and uiimage

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I solved it like kirander suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for right button with image:

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```